# I can not get messages in firestore (closed)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a stream builder and also stream.
I want to when I click to submit button, then I see the message which is sent by the user(for now only me).
What's wrong? Why can't I see my message on the screen? Help...

Here my alertdialog button which has textformfield, and user can use it and send messages.

```
 Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Submit"),
                    onPressed: () {
                    
                      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messages').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).set({
                         'message' : alertDialogText,
                      'timestamp' : DateTime.now()
                      });

                    },
                  ),
                )
```

Here, the part which is i want to get messages in my card

```
 class HomeScreenUI extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Consumer<FirestoreAuthentication>(
          builder: (context, fsAuth, child) {
              return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: fsAuth.firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
              return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(...)
```

and Card has messages which are sended by user:

```
                          Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                                child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  right: 8.0, top: 11.0),
                              child: Text(
                                "Message from user but for now it's string",
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 13),
                              ),
                            )),
                          ],
                        ),
)
```

finally screenshot in my firestore (if i send message it goes to here):
[image]

Comment: Do not paste screenshots. Writing your code is more proper to get an answer.

Comment: @Akif i have just edited my problem,and i'll wait answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Card you have mistake with acess data from field.  I see that you try to get data from field "mesaj" instead of field "message", that why you get error with text "field does not exists".